# How can I fix this python code to get all of the names of the people in the table I am referencing in the code?

Tags: python, web-scraping, find, screen-scraping, page-inspector

I am trying to get python to give me the names of the State Senators from Alabama on Ballotpedia. However, the code I put together is only giving me the title I requested from the url but I am not getting any names. Here is my current python code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

list = ['https://ballotpedia.org/Alabama_State_Senate']

temp_dict = {}

for page in list:
    r = requests.get(page)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')

    temp_dict[page.split('/')[-1]] = [item.text for item in 
soup.select("table.bptable gray sortable tablesorter 
jquery-tablesorter a")]

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(temp_dict, 
orient='index').transpose()
```

I believe my error is in this line:

```
    temp_dict[page.split('/')[-1]] = [item.text for item in soup.select("table.bptable gray sortable tablesorter jquery-tablesorter a")]
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

This seems to work for me:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://ballotpedia.org/Alabama_State_Senate"

response = requests.get(url)
response.raise_for_status()

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")

for row in soup.find(id="officeholder-table").select("tr:not([colspan])"):
    name = row.select_one("td:nth-of-type(2)").text
    print(name)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to get all info:

```
holders = soup.select("#officeholder-table")
targets = holders[0].select('tr')
for target in targets:
    print(target.text)
```

Output:

```
Alabama State Senate District 20
Linda Coleman-Madison
Democratic 
2006
```

etc.